# Grant "full disk access" to sandboxed applications permanently

Tags: macos, high-sierra, security, permission, sandbox

I'm using Microsoft Office 2016 (not 365) on macOS High Sierra. There's an annoying issue where I can open files normally but when I select a file from the "recently opened" menu it opens a dialog where I need to choose the file and grant permission. But I have already gave permission, not once, not twice, but multiple times. It seems likes Office just "forgets" about its permission to open files that it has already opened each restart.

I tried to disabled the sandbox by first changing `com.apple.security.app-sandbox` from `true` to `false` in the binary, and by signing it manually with the same entitlements but `com.apple.security.app-sandbox` disabled, both of which did not crash the application but did not solve the issue: now there is no files in the "recently opened" menu, which defeats the whole purpose. I'm sure that it can now open any file it wants, but that's useless without a "recently opened" menu.

Is there a way to grant full disk access to a sandboxed application permanently?

Comment: Granting this is normally permanent - no extra step needed. I wonder what is broken or changing on your OS or if the apps are updating or changing themselves somehow?

Comment: @bmike Do you know where this information is stored?

Comment: I am wondering if this is an issue that will actually yield to running disk utility and repair permissions? Often times that is a "fix" that doesn't actually fix the problem (remember "rebuild the desktop?"), but as this **is** a permissions issue...